# What is the purpose of OpenVPN's /etc/openvpn/{client,server} directories?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, debian

Ubuntu/Debian OpenVPN package contains 2 mysterious directories:

```
dpkg -L openvpn
...
/etc/openvpn/client
/etc/openvpn/server
...
```

I'm wondering what is the purpose of those directories? All tutorials advice placing files directly in `/etc/openvpn/` and init/systemd scripts also pick config files from there.

Chroot? But then, why 2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In v2.4 they introduced new systemd service profiles tailored for client resp. server applications.

> As of OpenVPN v2.4, upstream is shipping systemd unit files to provide
>   a fine grained control of each OpenVPN configuration as well as trying
>   to restrict the capabilities the OpenVPN process have on a system.
>
> These new unit files separates between client and server profiles. 
>   The configuration files are kept in separate directories, to provide
>   clarity of the profile they run under.
>
> Typically the client profile cannot bind to any ports below port 1024
>   and the client configuration is always started with --nobind.

[source](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/distro/systemd/README.systemd)

It remains backward compatible, i.e. you can still store your `.conf` file in `/etc/openvpn`.

- If your configuration is in  `/etc/openvpn/MyVpn.conf`,
  use `systemctl start openvpn@MyVpn` to start the service
- If your configuration is in `/etc/openvpn/client/MyVpn.conf`,
  use `systemctl start openvpn-client@MyVpn` to start the service
- If your configuration is in `/etc/openvpn/server/MyVpn.conf`,
  use `systemctl start openvpn-server@MyVpn` to start the service

Comment: Please see szr's answer for corrections. The .service file does not exist in the beginning.

Comment: fixed. ty all .

Comment: Placing config files in the client folder does not seem to work with AUTOSTART="all"

Comment: And the user documentation, which lists the commonly needed systemctl incantations, is at https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Systemd

Answer (score 5):

I'm unable to post a comment above in response to 3dGrabber's answer since my reputation in this neck of the SE woods is too low. I wanted to point out a mistake in said answer for those who come via searching so they aren't left scratching their heads when this fails somewhat cryptically.

`systemctl start openvpn-client@MyVpn.service` should be:

`systemctl start openvpn-client@MyVpn`

and

`systemctl start openvpn-server@MyVpn.service` should be:

`systemctl start openvpn-server@MyVpn`

The `.service` suffix was likely mistaken from the file that's created upon `systemctl enable ...`